# Call ruby class by name with round brackets

Tags: ruby, class

I have this class:

```
class Option
  # ORM's properties
  def self.get( id )
    # some ORM action
    "result of #{id}"
  end
end
```

And I can call `Option.get :setting` to receive a result. How do I write the class if I want to call `Option(:setting)` like in `String(42)` (which returns `"42"`) to get the same result as `Option#get`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` is actually a method in the [Kernel module](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-String):

> **String(arg) → string**
>
> Converts *arg* to a `String` by calling its `to_s` method.

You'll find `Array`, `Float`, and friends in the same place. Kernel is included in Object and that's where all the methods that are used like plain global functions go. You could monkey patch Kernel:

```
module Kernel
  def Option(id)
    Option.get(id)
  end
end
```

Or make your own module with a method like that and make people include it if they want access to say `Option(11)`.